# Unbinding event of child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I've an anchor within an list-item. Both elements have an event. I'd like to avoid clicking the list-item when clicking the anchor within.

I'd like to avoid chaos. I found this functions but I wasn't able to use them as I wanted:

- http://api.jquery.com/off/
- http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

That's the **code**:

```
// HTML
<ul>
    <li id="1">Item #1 <a href="" class="delete">[DEL]</a></li>
    <li id="2">Item #2 <a href="" class="delete">[DEL]</a></li>
    <li id="3">Item #3 <a href="" class="delete">[DEL]</a></li>
    <li id="4">Item #4 <a href="" class="delete">[DEL]</a></li>    
</ul>

// JS
$("ul").sortable();

$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    alert("list-item clicked.");
});

$(document).on("click", "a.delete", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm("Del?")) {
        alert("list-item clicked.");
    }
    // do nothing
});
```

Here's a **fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/UtE87/1/

What's the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the event propagation, you need to stop the event propagation. It can be done by calling `e.stopPropagation()` but since you are preventing the default action also, you can do both by returning false from the event handler

```
$(document).on("click", "a.delete", function(e) {
    if (confirm("Del?")) {
        console.log("list-item a clicked.");
    }
    // do nothing

    return false; //prevent default and stop propagation
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Rq4hP/)

Comment: That simple, wow. Shame on me. Thanks, I'll accept your answer as soon as I'm allowed to!

Comment: @Mr.Bombastic: Note that this only works because jQuery is doing some magic in the background. You are using *event delegation*, so both handlers are bound to the same element. Without jQuery, `e.stopPropagation()` wouldn't work here (unfortunately the documentation doesn't explain what exactly happens).

Answer (score 1):

You can check which element was click on and only run the list item click function if the delete element wasn't clicked.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k5sdC/1/

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).is('a.delete')){
        alert("list-item clicked.");
    }
});
```